# Error fatal: libssh.h: No such file or directory NETBEANS

Tags: c++, netbeans, libssh

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <libssh.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

I have that code, and when compiling the error fatal of no Libssh.h is appearing, but when i SHIFT+CLICK over the libssh.h include instruction i jump to the file that already exist and is installed.

I have include it on Netabeans options for C++ compiling.

Any ideas?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The search path of Netbeans is probably different than search path of the compiler. On my machine `libssh.h` is in `/usr/include/libssh/libssh.h`. You can try to change your include:

```
#include <libssh/libssh.h>
```

Or change compiler options to add `/usr/include/libssh/` to its search path.

Comment: I am using windows! I have add the include path on Tools - Options - C++ - The path is on a personal folder, not on a netbean folder.